# FindFit runs extremely slow for my Function,how do I optimize this?

Tags: numerics, fitting

My function is the first order Bessel Function, and I am basically just trying to get this to fit in a way that does not take forever.

I define the function as follows, (it seems to work faster if I explicity define the function instead of using the special function SphericalBesselJ):

```
F[q_?NumericQ, ra_?NumericQ, rb_?NumericQ, px_?NumericQ] :=px NIntegrate[((3 (4 Pi)/3 ra rb^2 1/(q rb (1 + x^2 ((ra/rb)^2 - 1)))^3 (Sin[q rb (1 + x^2 ((ra/rb)^2 - 1))] - (q rb (1 + x^2 ((ra/rb)^2 - 1)) Cos[q rb (1 + x^2 ((ra/rb)^2 - 1))])))^2),{x,0,1}]
```

In order to test the function I have simulated the function with random noise component that adds a 10% relative error in the data

```
TestData = Array[#1/1024*2.5 + 0*#2 &, {1024, 2}];

Do[
TestData[[n, 2]] = 
F[TestData[[n, 1]], 4.5, 6.8, 1]*RandomReal[{1 - .1, 1 + .1}]
, {n, 1024}]
```

In order to compute the fit I use a NormFunction that computes that uses the relative residuals instead of the absolute residuals as follows. The norm function I use is called weightedNorm[residuals].

```
weightedNorm[residuals_] := Norm[residuals/TestData[[All, 2]]]
IntensityWeightedParams = FindFit[TestData, {F[q, ra, rb,p],
                                 {0 < ra < 10, 5 < rb < 15}}, {{ra,4.5}, {rb, 6.8},{p,1}}, q,
                                 NormFunction -> weightedNorm, MaxIterations -> 10, Method -> NMinimize]
```

This fitting works particularly well when I am not solving a numerical integral, i.e. if I use a function that is purely algebraic, however, when I run this particular fit with even a single iteration as shown here the fit takes approximately 250s.

Comment: If someone asked me for an estimate about the quality of your post, I would say it's in the best 5% of first posts here. Therefore, welcome here. Please skim over the [FAQ] and read how voting and accepting of answers works here. (I'll remove the last sentence of your post. Really not needed)

Comment: What is `u`? It is not defined.

Comment: `u` cant be a numeric  argument to `P` and the integration variable inside..(?).

Comment: @george2079 Ahh, sorry, haven't seen it in the integrate call. That makes even less sense.

Comment: `MaxIterations->1` makes no sense, it basically says do one eval and return the initial guess.

Comment: u is a parameter that is only used in the integral, it does not need to be defined, it is not a physical parameter. The integral seems to work fine in it's current form. This is just how you evaluate this numerical integral. Max iterations being set to 1 was so I could test the speed of each iteration, and it is quite slow. Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't work it throws the error `"Raw object nn cannot be used as an iterator. "` where `nn` is whatever value you supply for u. ( some value is required by the `?NumericQ` )  Its a good idea when you post a question to start a clean session and copy-paste your own code from the web back into mathematica to verify it still works.  ( `IVsqData` is also not defined )

Comment: Some comments: `P` should not have `u` as a parameter; your options for `NIntegrate` are malformed; `IVsqData` should be `TestData`. Apart from that, try `Method -> {NMinimize, Method -> "NelderMead"}` as a parameter for `FindFit`. It may not help that much, but the only constrained method `FindMinimum` offers is nonlinear interior point, which for some reason is very slow. `NMinimize` has a different approach to constrained minimization that could be faster. However, best of all would be to eliminate your constraints and modify the function so that unwanted values are made explicitly invalid.

Comment: Thanks, first I edited this, I realized that I had some old variables that were not quite relevant in the current program, I appreciate you pointing that out. I removed the integral parameter "x" from the functional form. The program should work now if copy and pasted as is... sorry about that. A question I had for you was, I am not sure what you mean by "modify the function so that unwanted values are made explicity invalid". For example, my parameters are all real positive numbers, is there a way to do this that is computationally faster than using constraints?

Comment: Add `Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}` in `NIntegrate` may help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an answer at all but some insight. Let's first define two global variables we will use for looking at how fast your integral is evaluated:

```
calledIntegrate = 0;
evalStep = 0;
```

Now, let me redefine your target function by compiling the integrand to make it faster. Additionally, we will increase `calledIntegrate` on each call:

```
With[{
  cf = Compile[{{q, _Real, 0}, {ra, _Real, 0}, {rb, _Real, 0}, {x, _Real, 0}},
    ((3 (4 Pi)/3 ra rb^2 1/(q rb (1 + x^2 ((ra/rb)^2 - 1)))^3 (Sin[
           q rb (1 + x^2 ((ra/rb)^2 - 1))] - (q rb (1 + 
              x^2 ((ra/rb)^2 - 1)) Cos[q rb (1 + x^2 ((ra/rb)^2 - 1))])))^2)]
 },
 Module[{int},
  (* int is only a wrapper to force x to be numeric *)
  int[q_?NumericQ, ra_?NumericQ, rb_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := cf[q, ra, rb, x];
  FHali[q_?NumericQ, ra_?NumericQ, rb_?NumericQ, px_?NumericQ] := 
    (calledIntegrate++; 
     px NIntegrate[int[q, ra, rb, x], {x, 0, 1}])
  ]
 ]
```

Now initialize you test data

```
TestData = Array[#1/1024*2.5 + 0*#2 &, {1024, 2}];
Do[
  TestData[[n, 2]] = FHali[TestData[[n, 1]], 4.5, 6.8, 1]*RandomReal[{1 - .1, 1 + .1}], 
{n, 1024}];
```

and now run the fit

```
Dynamic[{calledIntegrate, evalStep}]

weightedNorm[residuals_] := Norm[residuals/TestData[[All, 2]]]
IntensityWeightedParams = 
 FindFit[TestData, {FHali[q, ra, rb, p], {0 < ra < 10, 
    5 < rb < 15}}, {{ra, 4.5}, {rb, 6.8}, {p, 1}}, q, 
  NormFunction -> weightedNorm, MaxIterations -> 10, 
  Method -> "NMinimize", EvaluationMonitor :> evalStep++]
```

After some seconds, I have over 30000 calls to `fHali` but only 30 evaluation steps. I guess no matter how fast you can get your target function, it will never be fast enough so that you can use it with this approach.

### Edit

One very crude idea is to skip `NIntegrate`. You will loose all the fancy stepping and adaption algorithms and I'm sure if the integrand is evil, the world will explode but maybe, it will give you an initial guess for your parameters. What I do is taking the same compiled code only that I'm simply dividing the interval `[0,1]` equally and replace the integration by a simple sum:

```
With[{cf = 
   Compile[{{q, _Real, 0}, {ra, _Real, 0}, {rb, _Real, 0}, {x, _Real, 
      0}}, ((3 (4 Pi)/
         3 ra rb^2 1/(q rb (1 + x^2 ((ra/rb)^2 - 1)))^3 (Sin[
           q rb (1 + x^2 ((ra/rb)^2 - 1))] - (q rb (1 + 
              x^2 ((ra/rb)^2 - 1)) Cos[
             q rb (1 + x^2 ((ra/rb)^2 - 1))])))^2), 
    Parallelization -> True, CompilationTarget -> "C", 
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}],
  points = Table[x, {x, 0, 1, 1/100.}]},
 FHali[q_?NumericQ, ra_?NumericQ, rb_?NumericQ, px_?NumericQ] :=   
  px Plus @@ cf[q, ra, rb, points]/Length[points]
 ]
```

When I compare the execution time of 1000 calls with your original `F` (you need to define it again!)

```
AbsoluteTiming[Do[#[1.1, 4.5, 6.8, 1], {1000}];] & /@ {FHali, F}
```

it is 0.04s compared to 5.3s which is a factor of about 130. I'll take the `TestData` that was created with your proper function, but I use my crude approximation for the fit. Note that I removed the initial guesses for the parameters (and additionally changed the `Method` setting as suggested by Olek!)

```
steps = 0;
Dynamic[steps]

weightedNorm[residuals_] := Norm[residuals/TestData[[All, 2]]]
IntensityWeightedParams = 
 FindFit[TestData, {FHali[q, ra, rb, p], {0 < ra < 10, 
    5 < rb < 15}}, {ra, rb, p}, q, NormFunction -> weightedNorm, 
  Method -> {"NMinimize", Method -> "NelderMead"},
  EvaluationMonitor :> steps++]
```

After **only 16s (!!)** I got as answer

> {ra -> 4.51598, rb -> 6.77539, p -> 0.993664}

which is not bad at all if we think about that we used just 100 sampling points. Maybe this helps you think about an alternative approach for your problem.

Comment: This was extremely useful actually. Thank you. Although, you are right, this does not really make the program work, but it does mean that I need to fundamentally rethink how quickly I either evaluate this function, or how I perform the fitting. Not sure which yet though.

Comment: @GregoryFahs Please see my edit. I approximated your integral with a stupid sum and it doesn't seem to work that bad. Maybe you can use this as an initial guess for a more expensive method.

Comment: I agree with you, reducing the number of sampling points could help. The number of points I am using is actually defined by the detector we use, but that number is fairly arbitrary as far as I am concerned, really I only need to use a number that follow 2^n for the sampling number. Additionally, this fit now only takes 15 minutes even if I include 1000 points, I think the key was to make the integral run faster by compiling it as you did. This gives me a lot to play around with, I really appreciate all of your help.

Comment: Just for completeness I figured I would add in what this program actually does. It is computing theoretical data for small angle x-ray scattering of dilute solutions of ellipsoids. Essentially the function FHali as halirutan has defined it is the form factor for ellipsoids of rotation (This is a Fourier transform of all orientations of an ellipsoid). Here is a link to the equation I am fitting: http://www.ncnr.nist.gov/resources/sansmodels/Ellipsoid.html

Comment: `NMinimize` I think will use differential evolution by default, which (being a population-based method) is notoriously profligate with its use of objective function evaluations per iteration. That's why I specified Nelder-Mead in my comment above.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Ah, haven't seen that but I was really surprised that so many evaluation steps are necessary. In fact, I had hoped you answer somethings since I knew you did a lot of work with `NMinimize`.

Comment: @OleksandrR. This is awesome. With your setting you can remove the `MaxIteration` option **and** increase the sum-sampling to 1000 and the algorithm finishes after 336 steps (or about 60 seconds) with a very exact parameter fit! (worked it into the answer, thanks)